# Send parameters to child Knitr file

Tags: r, parameters, knitr

I have some identical sections in a document but the entry data's files are differents.
Is it possible to make a master knitr file who all sections are wrote and call a child Knitr-file,  who have the code for the corps of all section (identical code), but take as parameter  the datafiles ?
Lile if we passed some parameters to a R-script sourced in another script.

Comment: +1 for the use of master + child

Comment: see example 020: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples

Answer (score 2):

One solution is this workflow:

1. Write the knitr file (Rnw or rmd, whatever) which uses a few variables that are not defined in that script.
2. Write a function that knits the knitr file, and takes a bunch of arguments that the knitr file should use (these should correspond in name to the variables I refer to in 1.)
3. Then knit using the envir argument (assuming it is an rmd file):

---

```
knitrenv <- new.env()
assign("someargument", someargument, knitrenv)
assign("someargument2", someargument2, knitrenv)
knit2html(myrmdfile, envir=knitrenv)
```

Comment: It should be just about, except replace `knit2html` with `knit2pdf`